# Invert columns in Twitter Bootstrip Grid

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

Does Twitter Bootstrap not support inverting columns in their grid? Similar to the .pull_4 and .push_4 in 960.gs? I see they have offset4 which works like push_4, but no way to pull columns left?

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="span8 offset4">Content in Column 2</div>
    <div class="span4">Sidebar in Column 1</div>
</div>
```

**Update**

I still can't figure out how to do this.  I tried the following, but margins get all messed up...

```
  <div class="row-fluid">
        <div class="span8 pull-right" style="background:red">
            Right column, First in HTML
        </div>
        <div class="span4" style="background:green">
            Lef column, Second in HTML
        </div>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `pull-right` or `pull-left`; see below:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="span8">Content in Column 2</div>
    <div class="span4 pull-right">Sidebar in Column 1</div>
</div>
```

Comment: That's what I would have thought, but it doesn't work that way. I want span8 to come first in the HMTL, but displayed in the right column.  In your example span4 is already right aligned.